# php://input Uplaod image with image type

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop, image-uploading

I'm implementing a **drag and drop image uploader** with ajax call, 
I saw a tutorial on this and implemented like this, with this code I can save the image in .jpg format only! *(or any one format that I specify in the code)*

uploaded image saved in **php://input** folder before and we need to grab that image from that temp folder to save that in the server,

but they didn't tell anything to change image format as per the **image type**,

now I want to **upload** the image in the **original format**, how can I collect image information while it is uploading?

here is the code

```
    <?php
        $str =file_get_contents('php://input');
        $filename = md5(time()).'.jpg';
        $path = 'upload/'.$filename;
        file_put_contents($path,$str);
        echo $path;
```

here is some JS for taking the image and sending ajax request:

```
    $(function(){

        //select the drop container
        var obj = $('.drop');

        // dragover event listener
        obj.on('dragover',function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).css('border',"2px solid #16a085");
        });

        //drop event listener
        obj.on('drop',function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).css('border',"2px dotted #bdc3c7");

            //get the files
            var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
            var file =files[0];
            //console.log(file);

            //upload data using the xhr object
            upload(file);

        });

        function upload(file){

            //create xhr object
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            //initiate request
            xhr.open('post','drop.php',true);

            //set headers
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',"multipart/form-data");
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name',file.fileName);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Size',file.fileSize);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Type',file.fileType);

            //send the file
            xhr.send(file);
        }

    });
```

Comment: You're sending the file type in the header `X-File-Type`, so try and get it with: `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE']`.

Comment: no i can't, i tried just now, it is saving without extension!

Comment: What do you mean by _"saving without extension"_? Check what that header contains with `var_dump($_SERVER)`.It might be the mime type and not the extension.

Comment: it is saving file as **__some_random_hashed_file_name__.undefined**

Comment: 1. Again, dump `$_SERVER` and see what it contains. It might be the mime type and not the extension. 2. Check what `file.fileType` contains in the console, when you're setting the header. 3. Look at my first comment again, I misspelled the header name but has updated it.

Comment: yeah, with that **$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE']** only im getting .undefigned type,

Comment: thanks dude, i fixed the problem, and answered my question :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I fixed this problem.

there was no problem with PHP to catch headers, as **Magnus Eriksson** said *$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE']* works fine, but problem was **while sending ajax header** we set header type and size wrong.

i logged file data and find **type** and **size** but i set header as **fileType** and **fileSize**

changed the code and here is the code before and after :

**BEFORE:** AJAX request:

> //set headers
> xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',"multipart/form-data");
> xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name',file.fileName);
> xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Size',file.fileSize);
> xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Type',file.fileType);

and PHP:

```
$str =file_get_contents('php://input');
$filename = md5(time()).'.jpg';
$path = 'upload/'.$filename;
file_put_contents($path,$str);
echo $path;
```

**AFTER:** AJAX request:

> //set headers
> xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',"multipart/form-data");
> xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name',file.fileName);
> xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Size',file.size);
> xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Type',file.type);

and PHP:

```
$str =file_get_contents('php://input');
$ext = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_TYPE'];
$e = explode("/",$ext);
$ext = $e[1];
$filename = md5(time()).'.'.$ext;
$path = 'upload/'.$filename;
file_put_contents($path,$str);
echo $path;
```

this code is working fine :)